# Pycharm not recognizing Django project

Tags: django, pycharm

I've seen similar questions but they don't solve my problem.

I have a correctly installed django project. I haven't being able to make Pycharm recognize it. I can't get file name completions (i.e `static` files), imports from the project apps aren't recognized and neither are urls tags, can't run the server ... How can I solve this?

Comment: do you think you set up pycharm correctly so it supports django? if not yet, here is shown how to https://www.django-tips.com/tip/how-to-setup-pycharm-for-django/31/

Comment: What have you configured? Have you set your project interpreter in pycharm? Enabled django support in languages & frameworks? Made sure the settings module is correct in the environment variables config?

Comment: A quick checklist, project interpreter in settings is set to a python env with django installed? also in case you have anything unusual with directory structure, enabled django support telling it `django project root`, `settings file` and `manage script`?

Comment: buddy we would need some more information related to this, have you enabled Django support?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all the suggestions, I'll check them all out and come back with updates.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Solved the question. GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't selecting the correct folder when opening the project. I opened the whole `virtualenv` folder with Pycharm cause I wanted quick access to the `activate` file in `/bin` where I keep my environment variables.

The solution was to delete the `.idea` folder and open the specific django project folder. I thought there was a workaround to this but there wasn't. The question still remains if there is a way to add the `activate` file in the `/bin` directory of the `virtualenv` to the project, even if it is outside the project root.